# Докер контейнере Nginx proxy_pass на другие порты не работает?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Есть тестовый PHP проект используется докер

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: temp-name-api
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - temp-name-network 

  test:
    build: ./test
    container_name: temp-name-test
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - temp-name-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: temp-name-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.prod:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - api
      - test
    networks:
      - temp-name-network

networks:
  temp-name-network:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name side-project.loc;
  
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

  index index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location /api {
      proxy_pass http://api:3001/public/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location /test {
      proxy_pass http://test:3002;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }


  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  error_page 404 /index.php;
}
```

api/DockerFile

```
FROM php:8.0.6-fpm-alpine3.13

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001
```

test/DockerFile

```
FROM php:8.0.6-fpm-alpine3.13

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3002
```

При использовании  `http://side-project.loc/api/`  или  `http://side-project.loc/test/`  получаю nginx ошибку
`404 Not Found`  в папке `test` и в папке `api/public`  есть  `index.php` файл , докер запускается без ошибок
nginx access и error лог файлы  пусты.

в чем ошибка почему данная конструкция не работает ?

**UPD**

После `docker-compose logs -f` только это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А контейнеры api и test работают?

Comment: @PotroNik   Да контейнеры запускаются без ошибок

Comment: a `side-project.loc` резолвится в вашем DNS? Попробуйте по ip подключение установить

Comment: @PotroNik  Да все реализовано  в windows 10 host файле, переход по side-project.loc  даёт стандартный  nginx page ответ

Comment: Ну тогда как вариант проверить `location /api/ {...` proxy_pass оставить такой как есть, возможно чть с таки локейшеном дописываетмя к url api, т.е. вместо ожидаемого редиректа `http://api:3001/public/` оперенаправляется сюда `http://api:3001/public/api`. Насколько я помню, логи nginx перенаправлены в stdout, поэтому должны отображаться командой `docker-compose logs -f`

Comment: @PotroNik   после   ```docker-compose logs -f``` 
только это 
[terminal](https://prnt.sc/13bb7r3)